# android studio; how to make application log user activity

Tags: java, android, logging, android-studio

Im trying to make an app for a specific location, and wanted to also include some sort of logger, where it records all activity that a user does within the application. However I have no idea how to go about doing this.
So far ive made a page where the user enters their name, and i wanted that activity to hold the logger, but after looking around, ive found nothing to help me make the logger for android apps.
Ive been trying it myself by using the logger.logger util, but ive had no progress.
(The logger is supposed to log all activity across the whole app, but ive been having trouble figuring out how to also make it record user activity outside of the one activity.
Here is what ive made as the logger so far.

Thanks for any help.

```js
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("app_log");
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
FileHandler fh;
try {

  // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
  fh = new FileHandler(C: \Users\ kevin\ Documents\ app_log.txt);
  logger.addHandler(fh);
  //logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);  
  SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
  fh.setFormatter(formatter);

  // the following statement is used to log any messages  
  logger.info(" applicaiton log");

} catch (SecurityException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being ran on your android, correct?
That is a windows file path, not a Unix one.
Does "C:\Users\kevin\Documents\" exists in your android environment?

Comment: im using the android emulator within android studio, sadly i dont know the best directory when it comes to making a txt file within android

Comment: The android emulator does not use windows paths. Try `openFileInput("log");` and read up on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: thanks, ill check that now, but how would i go about doing the logger?

Comment: `System.out.println();` is good for simple output. However I suspect that you are looking for a logger that includes things such as a timestamp. Read up on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html for android logging documentation.

Comment: i understand how the logger works, i just dont knw how to make the logger work throughout the application (through all activities) do i need to work with the manifest or is there something else i need to add onto my logger code, other than editing my directory for the text file?

Comment: Add a static declaration to a tag you'll use and you should be good.

Comment: slightly tired, can u give me an example of a static declaration for android programming for logging?

Comment: `private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";` Straight from the documentation I sent you.